# How to handle error ": 'Control's handle must be created first.'"?

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I ran into an error `Control's handle must be created first.` The code returns the error

```
  model1.SetView(viewType.Trimetric, true, false);
```

I already tried  `model1.CreateControl();` before the code above executed but still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `SetView()` method call in the `Form.OnLoad()` (WinForms) or `Window.OnContentRendered()` (WPF) when the `Model` control is ready to be used.